# Weird graphics failure / horizontal blue lines in the top bar

Tags: bug, status-norepro, microsoft-edge

So uhm, I thought my screen was broken for a second. What's going on?

It's occurring on both StackOverflow and Meta. Resizing the window changes the size/effect of it.

Reloading a question/post (like this one) adds the effect over the entire page.

Reproduces in Edge (Chromium). Doesn't reproduce in Safari.

[image: The background of the top bar is full of rows of dark and light blue horizontal blocks of random size.]

I managed to capture the fullscreen effect as well:

[image: The effect above is happening to the entire page below the top bar.]

Comment: Operating system? Asking because https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251248169

Comment: @SamuelLiew Catalina 10.15.4 (regular macOS on a Macbook Pro)

Comment: Most likely an OS issue, since you have the exact same OS version as the one I linked. The fix is https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204063

Comment: @SamuelLiew weird. SO is the only website I frequent where I see this issue though. And only in Edge. I'm guessing it's an Edge bug, since I had an Edge update this morning.

Comment: Also, Resetting NVRAM is Apple's go-to solution for all problems, whenever they suggest that, I'd take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Regular restart removed it, so at least this confirms it's a platform issue (either in Edge or MacOS). Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't reproduce in newest Chrome on Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: @SamuelLiew the issue is back, this time on Big Sur (11.2.2 (20D80))

Comment: And like last time, a reboot of the Mac fixed it.